# How can I maintain selections of 'mat-list-option' within 'cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have an implementation of `mat-list-option` to be used inside `cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport`. The actual project I'm working on is based on `Angular 14`. However, to achieve this implementation, I found a demo project in `Angular 11`.

In this demo project, scrolling works great, and selections of each item are remembered on each scroll as expected.

However, the same approach for `Angular 14` doesn't work as expected. After a selection and scrolling, the selection is gone.

Below is the HTML template to give you an idea of my implementation. The `selectionChange` binding handles each selection and calls the `select` and `deselect` methods of the `SelectionModel`, which you can find in the `.ts` file

```
 <mat-selection-list (selectionChange)="onSelectionChange($event)">
      <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport [itemSize]="20" class="example-viewport">
        <mat-list-option
          *cdkVirtualFor="let item of list;"
          [value]="item"
          [selected]="selection.isSelected(item)"
          >{{item}}
        </mat-list-option>
      </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
    </mat-selection-list>
```

Below, you can find the `.ts` file, which includes the `SelectionModel` object to interact with the `mat-selection` list, handle selections, the `list` variable to manage lots of dummy items, and the `onCheckboxChange` method used for the `selectionChange` output binding:

```
 selection = new SelectionModel(true);
  list = Array.from(Array(10000).keys());

  onCheckboxChange(selection: MatSelectionListChange) {
    const changedOptions = selection.options;
    for (const option of changedOptions) {
      if (option.selected) {
        this.selection.select(option.value);
      } else {
        this.selection.deselect(option.value);
      }
    }
  }
```

I have conducted extensive research and used ChatGPT to solve the issue here, but I couldn't find anything useful. Can you help me make this work as expected in an up-to-date Angular version?

Here you can find the `Stackblitz` examples of each implementation and Angular version.

Angular 11 (Demo working as Expected) : https://stackblitz.com/edit/virtual-scrolling-selection-list-mpawp4?file=src%2Fapp%2Flist-selection-example.html

Angular 14 (Not working as Expected) : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b3c9dv-v3pya1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-overview-example.ts

Answer (score 1):

To improve rendering performance, `*cdkVirtualFor` caches previously created views after they are no longer needed. When a new view would normally be created, a cached view is reused instead. The size of the view cache can be adjusted via the `templateCacheSize` property; setting this size to 0 disables caching. If your templates are expensive in terms of memory you may wish to reduce this number to avoid spending too much memory on the template cache.

```
<mat-selection-list (selectionChange)="onCheckboxChange($event)">
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport [itemSize]="48" class="scroll-viewport">
<div *cdkVirtualFor="let item of list;templateCacheSize: 0">
  <mat-list-option      
    [selected]="selection.isSelected(item)"
    [value]="item"
    class="custom-list-option">{{ item }}</mat-list-option>
</div>
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
</mat-selection-list>
```